# saving textfield input under a variable

Tags: java, variables

Hello :) I'm trying to implement a sequential search in java
the point is to make it get the number i give in in a text field and search for it in the array. i'm not sure how to get the value and save it under a variable tho, because I need it to be int so i can compare it to the numbers in the array, but i have to convert it to string so i can display it in the textfield at the end?

so I named the variable under which i wish to save the value of the number "x" and tried x=textfield.getText() as textfield1 is the field i want to type the number in but it doesn't work...

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
int array []=new int [6];
int x;
private void genActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
 for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
  {
  array[i]=(int)(Math.random()*49+1);
 }
x= textfield1.getText();
 for (int i = 0; i < array; i++) {
if (array[i] == x)
  System.out.println( "Element found at index " + array[i]);
```

error "string cannot be converted to int"

Comment: Check out `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: i'm not sure how to use that i'm still a beginner and i don't really know much about programming could you help me with that?

Comment: `int number = Integer.parseInt("1234");`

Comment: hello would it be like this         x=  Integer.parseInt(textfield1.getText()); ? thanks

Comment: try it and see what happens

Comment: it worked thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store a text into an int variable. int variables are used only for storing numbers like 1, 2, 3... You have to use a String variable.

Comment: but if I use a String variable then i can't check if my x number is the same as the number stored in the index i in the array (?)

Comment: @Manaws gave you the answer. Just try to test different solutions and read about java types. That´s one the most important features of Java language.

Answer (score 0):

As ccarpan said you are trying to store text into an Integer.

Either you use

```
String x = "";
x = textfield1.getText();
```

or you try to parse the Text to an Integer (if you are only using numbers)
like:

```
int x;
x = Integer.parseInt(textfield1.getText());
//throws an error if you are trying to write letters or symbols
```

Comment: hello, yes, the parseint was what i was looking for! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is first save the value as a String:

```
String x = textfield1.getText();
```

... because any value provided will be a valid String.

Then you attempt to parse the integer value:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(x);
```

Do this in 2 steps so that you can recover from Exception if someone enters an invalid integer value like 12J65K9 ... if you have learned how to do Exception handling.